# How well do native Chinese speakers do on the HSK6?

Tags: chinese, hsk

I see a fair number of posts and videos about native Chinese speakers taking the HSK6, or mock HSK6 exams, so I'm hoping to collect their scores in one place:

**Question**: How well do native Chinese speakers do on the HSK6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I've found available online:

| Date | Listening | Reading | Writing | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| May 2022 | - | 92% | - | Source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjHYYA-OywY); Chinese teacher gets 3 faulty sentence questions wrong, and one "fill in the blank" (part 2) question wrong. She takes the past exam paper H61000. She also has [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bli78vG8BcU) for the listening section, but I didn't find her marks (she noted she got question 3 wrong). |
| Nov 2021 | 97% | 98% | 78% | Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/qk9v5q/just_took_the_hsk_6_as_a_native_speaker_of/); actual HSK6 marks |
| Jun 2021 | - | - | - | Source: [Bilibili](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV14U4y1G7Ne); three youth had some wrong answers in the listening and reading sections; it's unclear precisely how well they did, but they found it difficult |
| Feb 2021 | - | - | - | Source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lE1-TDQu3H0); two questions wrong in the "faulty sentence" section |
| Aug 2020 | - | 92% | - | Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/i55gz3/native_speaker_here_took_an_online_sample_test_of/) ([exam with answers](http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSK/level6/H61003.pdf)) |
| Jul 2020 | - | 96% | - | Source: [Bilibili](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV17C4y1b7bh); she seems to be a Chinese teacher; I'm a bit confused by the video, but it seems she got 2 wrong in the reading section, and gave herself 75% in the writing section, and a total score of 257 out of 300 (which would imply 86% in the listening section) |
| Aug 2019 | - | - | - | Source: [Bilibili](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1vt411F7fx); he answers 5 questions from the "faulty sentence" section, and gets 3 wrong |
| Oct 2018 | 99% | 95% | 82% | Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/9mf40z/comment/e7h62mh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3); comments "...what’s even harder is the writing. I’m a native speaker and a Chinese language instructor, and I was typing on a computer, so obviously there couldn’t be any blatant grammatical or spelling errors. They must be looking for a good prose rather than my mundane language." |
| Sep 2018 | - | - | - | Source: [YouKu](https://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMzgxMTkxMTYyOA==.html?spm=a2h0c.8166622.PhoneSokuUgc_1.dtitle); 6 participants answered 10 "faulty sentence" questions, with scores ranging from 3 to 8 |
| Sep 2018 | ~67% / ~89% | - | - | Source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOu_AEATQd4) ([audio and answers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TcngGwn1N8)); they answer 9 questions from the listening section; the lady got questions 3, 7, and 34 wrong, and the man got question 7 wrong |
| Aug 2018 | 94% | 94% | - | Source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/94undc/as_a_native_speaker_i_just_tried_a_practice_hsk_6/) ([exam with answers](http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSK/level6/H61001.pdf); [audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TcngGwn1N8)); I believe this test was taken by a Chinese teacher, who reports getting questions 16, 25, and 28 wrong in the listening section, and 52, 53, and 56 wrong in the reading section (all "faulty sentence questions") |
| Jun 2018 | - | - | - | Source: [Bilibili](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1HW411P7nC); he answered 10 "faulty sentence" questions, and got 2 wrong (question 55 and 59) |
| Feb 2018 | 96% | 90% | 89% | Source: [Improve Mandarin](https://improvemandarin.com/hsk6-vs-native-chinese/); took the actual HSK6; did not prepare. |
| ~2017 | - | ~92% | - | Source: [Quora](https://www.quora.com/In-China-is-it-true-that-as-long-as-you-pass-the-HSK-they-will-accept-you-into-a-university) (or [here](https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-to-learn-Chinese-to-pass-the-HSK-level-6)); "This test give me 45 minutes to finish.I spent 20 minutes." They took an exam from [here](http://www.chinesetest.cn/gosimexam.do). |
| Jun 2017 | ~75% | - | - | Source: [Bilibili](https://www.bilibili.com/video/av11273247/) ([exam with answers](http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSK/level6/H61005.pdf)); if I understood everything correctly, he answers a selection of 20 questions in the listening section; he got questions 5, 20, 23, 24, and 35 wrong |
| Jun 2017 | ~88% | - | - | Source: [Bilibili](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1vx41187a5) ([questions and answers](http://www.cup.edu.cn/IS/docs/2015-01/20150106160208937650.doc)); if I understood everything correctly, he answers a selection of 25 reading questions; he got questions 54, 61, and 81 wrong (he also pronounced 狭隘 as xiá'yì instead of xiá'ài) |
| Jun 2017 | - | - | - | Source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADg1BLT7EcI) (I believe he's using the textbook *汉语水平考试，模拟试题集*); says he struggles with "faulty sentence" questions; gets one correct and one wrong |
| Aug 2016 | ~100% | - | - | Source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHYNh9F4CeA) ([exam with answers](http://www.chinesetest.cn/userfiles/file/HSK6.pdf)); she answers 9 questions from the listening section, and claims she got them all correct, but it's unclear if she answered B or C for question 32. |

(I note that during the HSK6 exam, for the "faulty sentence" questions, the examinee is required to answer questions within around 1 minute, and multiple videos ignore this requirement.  I also note that the old past HSK6 exams from 10+ years ago are considered far easier than the current HSK6 exams.)

---

Available from the [chinesetest.cn website](http://www.chinesetest.cn/gonewcontent.do?id=5589743) are these plots from 2012, giving the scores of test takers with Chinese citizenship (87%+ are from Xinjiang province):

> [image]

The y-axis is "number of students" and the x-axes are "listening marks" (out of 50), "reading marks" (out of 50) and "listening/reading combined marks" (as a percentage).